# non-existing page/location tirggering 500 server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was testing something with my server responses for 404 and other errors, and 404 was working correctly.

I'd enter `example.com/page`, `example.com/directory/`, `example.com/directory/page`, and it'd return 404 errors as it should.

And then I tried `example.com/directory/page/string` (like 123 or key-words-here), and it returned 500 errors.

I'm using this code for `mod_rewrite`

```
# redirects index.html to /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# rewrites file.html to file

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

What can I do to turn these 500 errors into the proper 404s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely its looping, try adding this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

In your end rule. So it will look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# redirects index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# rewrites file.html to file
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```